# jQuery plugin structure

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the following as a basis for a jquery plugin but I seem to have some syntax issues from my .find onwards. The code within the click function won't get called and the class is not being applied. Can someone suggest where I may have gone wrong here please?

```
(function($){

        $.fn.expandCollapse = function(options){

             var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.expandCollapse.defaults, options);

             function initialize(){

                $(this).each(function(){
                    // code
                }).find("p").click(function(){
                    // code
                }).end().not(:first).addClass(opts.c);
              }
            initialize();

            return $(this);

        };

        $.fn.expandCollapse.defaults = {
            c: "collapsed"
        };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Would you mind posting some additional information? E.g., Example HTML that you're traversing, and what your .each() and .click() closures are doing.

Answer (score 4):

You have this snippet:

```
not(:first)
```

Try wrapping `':first'` in quotes.

Comment: Thanks Ron. That's cleared up the syntax errors, but for some reason nothing within the .click()(function(){ is being called. Is my syntax there correct? There are definately 
s to find.